# How can I get a PHP webpage to print every day of the year (2013)?

Tags: php, for-loop, strtotime

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to make a PHP webpage that prints out every day of the 2013 year like:

January 1, 2013
January 2, 2013
...........
...........
December 31, 2013

I have been playing with different variations of this code below, but I can't get the date to increment more than once.

```
$date = "2013-01-01";

for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 365; $counter++) {

$newdate = strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date));
$newdate = date('Y-m-j', $newdate);

echo "$newdate<br>";
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It's simple, when you are using `strtotime( string )`, there is the problem.

Other important thing is that you need to add the date to `$date` or add the `$counter` on `strtotime( originalDate . '+'.$counter.' day')`

**1 without counter using $date.**

```
<?php

$date = "2013-01-01";

for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 364; $counter++) {

    echo "$date<br>";

    $newdate = strtotime( $date . '+1 day');
    $newdate = date('Y-m-j', $newdate);
    $date = $newdate;

}

?>
```

**2 with counter:**

```
<?php

$date = "2013-01-01";

for ($counter = 0; $counter <= 364; $counter++) {

    $newdate = strtotime( $date . '+'.$counter.' day');
    $newdate = date('Y-m-j', $newdate);


    echo "$newdate<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You always use `$date` variable for calculating the date, but you are not changing it. Your loop will iterate 366 times (it started from 0, and ends with including 365). Also echo the `$date` first, or you will start from the 2nd of January

```
$date = "2013-01-01";

for ($counter = 0; $counter < 365; $counter++) {
    echo "$date<br>";
    $date = date('Y-m-j', strtotime('+1 day', strtotime($date)));
}
```